# Text scramble Javascript onload event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this script work on page load and not on mouseover and I tried many things none as worked

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.querySelector("h1#scramble").onmouseover = event => {
  let iteration = 0;

  clearInterval(interval);

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index < iteration) {
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }

        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)]
      })
      .join("");

    if (iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    iteration += 1 / 2;
  }, 6);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="scramble" data-value="Hello">Helloword</h1>
```

I have tried to change the `.onmouseover` to `.onload` but that did not work

Comment: You probably want to add the event listener to `document` instead of some element, a `h` doesn't really need to "load"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.onload`:

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

window.onload = () => {
  let text = document.querySelector("h1#scramble");
  let iteration = 0;

  clearInterval(interval);

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    text.innerText = text.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index < iteration) {
          return text.dataset.value[index];
        }

        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)]
      })
      .join("");

    if (iteration >= text.dataset.value.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    iteration += 0.5;
  }, 6);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="scramble" data-value="Hello">Helloword</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably completey ditching the eventhandler and doing

```
function scramble() {
  let elem = document.querySelector("#scramble");
  let iteration = 0;
  clearInterval(interval);

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    elem.innerText = elem.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index < iteration) {
          return elem.dataset.value[index];
        }

        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)]
      })
      .join("");

    if (iteration >= elem.dataset.value.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    iteration += 1 / 2;
  }, 6);
}

scramble()
```

and include this script at *the end* of your HTML. This way, it will be executed after all HTML has been rendered

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    function scramble() {
      ...
    }
    scramble();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```